# Find length of longest consecutive sequence in array of integers

Tags: kdb

Please help me with a function to find consecutive sequence in a list.

It is working for below list

```
q) list:100 4 200 1 3 2
q)st where (deltas st:asc list)=1
  1 2 3 4
q)count st where (deltas st:asc list)=1
   4
```

However below example not returning result as expected.

```
q)list
10 15 1 2 3 4 5 11 12
q)st where (deltas st:asc list)=1
1 2 3 4 5 11 12   // expected result is 1 2 3 4 5
q)count st where (deltas st:asc list)=1
7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar idea to Maurice's, but we can jump straight to the longest sequence without having to manipulate the list.

```
q)max deltas where not 1=deltas asc 10 15 1 2 3 4 5 11 12
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
q)list:10 15 1 2 3 4 5 11 12;
q)max count each"0"vs raze string 1=deltas asc list
5
q)max count each("0"vs raze string 1=deltas asc list)except enlist""
5
```

`1=deltas` would return a Boolean list of consecutive numbers if it exist. We can then group the `1b`s together by breaking it up using the `0b`s. We can do that by converting it to a `string` then using `vs` to break up the list. Then finally, we can get a `count` of `each` group of consecutive numbers and get the `max`.